# Fragment being replaced cannot removed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to replace FragmentB with FragmentA. The Fragment A consist of listView and FragmentB consist of some TextView. On click listview position 0 the FragmentB should replace FragmentA. Before replace, all two fragments appeared normal in MainActivity. After replacement FragmentA appeared on the bottom of FragmentB. It means FragmentB contents doesn't disappears but it should disappear.

FragmentA:

```
public class FragmentA extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    Get get;
    public interface Get {
        void getData(int s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            get = (Get) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {

            arrayList.add("a");
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        get.getData(position);
    }
}
```

FragmentB:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentA.Get{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void getData(int s) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if(s == 0) {




FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(s), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.zohaibsiddique.listfragment.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.example.zohaibsiddique.listfragment.FragmentA"
        android:id="@+id/fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.example.zohaibsiddique.listfragment.FragmentB"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_b.xml

```
package com.example.zohaibsiddique.listfragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Zohaib Siddique on 12/08/2016.
 */
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

Comment: May be background transparency is causing this issue.

Comment: Instead of adding `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment2, fragment);` try replacing like `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment);`

Comment: what will be the possible solution?

Comment: fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment);

Comment: i update code but the FragmentA appears on the bottom of FragmentB

Comment: make sure you have a background color of white or something on the FragmentB.

Comment: @bc120201817ZohaibSiddiq Please post your activity xml?

Comment: please see now @JagjitSingh

Comment: please see updated code @AkshayBhat

Comment: @bc120201817ZohaibSiddiq Add Your fragments at runtime. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your activity layout. FragmentB is on top of Fragment A. The simple solution to this would be create a LinearLayout in activity layout. Like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.zohaibsiddique.listfragment.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@id/fragment_container"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in `onCreate()` of activity, add first fragment :

```
FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Then create a method for adding FragmentB, and call this method when required.

```
public void addFragmentB() {
    FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: great. I also found this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code `fragmentTransaction.replace()` instead of `fragmentTransaction.add()`

Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

Answer (score 0):

```
   If(null!=fragment)
   fragment=null;
   switch(currentFragment){
   case A:
    fragment = new FragmentA();
    break;
    case B:
   fragment= new FragmentB();
   break;}
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(s), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Changes to be made:1. Remove fragment tags from your activity_main and have single Frame Layout
2.In fragmentTransaction.replace add respective id of framelayout of your activity_main.

PS: you can either implement switch case for current fragment as shown or have your own logic..